# ui controls for asp.net

Tags: website-design, forms, custom-control

i have been using the basic toolkit that is provided with VS 2008

I am currently looking for UI control toolkit from third party.

I am basically concentrating on Gridview, treeview, textboxes, hoover, buttons and graphs(piecharts)

Order of preference:

1.) Totally free( can be used commercially no royalties)

2.) semi free ( can be used as trial version or has some sort of licience)

3.) paid (but not as expensive as terelik and all..)

Can any one suggest any thing..

Comment: Ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a good quality set of UI controls for ASP.NET (or WinForms or WPF or XYZ) is an exercise that takes many hundreds of hours.

There are a lot of half-baked examples on CodeProject that demonstrate this - you can get a long way in a short time, but getting all the little details right takes a lot more time.

Essentially, there is a good reason why DevExpress, Telerik, Infragistics, SyncFusion and their competitors are expensive - and it's not because they're trying to rip you off.